# Where can i find literature about the $\frac{4}{3}$-conjecture for approximation of the Metric TSP?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np-complete, approximation, traveling-salesman

In Graph-Theory there are many ways for efficient approximation-algorithms to solve the Metric TSP. The best solution seems to be the Christofides Heuristic with a factor of 1.5 to the optimal solution. My Teacher said, there would be the so called $\frac{4}{3}$-conjecture, which states: there might be a approximation solution for the metric tsp, that has only a $\frac{4}{3}$-factor.

But i cannot find any literature or further information about this assumption. Maybe you can?

Comment: Related question on cs.theory: [Why is Metric TSP's best possible achieved approximation ratio believed to be 4/3?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/why-is-metric-tsps-best-possible-achieved-approximation-ratio-believed-to-be-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[On the Integrality Gap of the Subtour LP for the 1,2-TSP](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1630) provides some relevant references and discussion in the introduction..